# Google Sign-In 404 Error with swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-signin

link: [Simulator Screenshot of Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1E2um.png)

Hello,
I just had my laptop repaired/reset after some water damage and now when opening the app on Xcode 9 Beta and pressing the "Google Sign-in" button the link fails to sign in. This used to work perfectly before 3 weeks ago on Xcode 8 before the water spill incident so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

I tried submitting the failed link myself and that's where I got the 404 HTTP Request error.

I also checked to make sure that GoogleService-info.plist matched with what's on firebase and I made sure I reregistered the signing of this app to my appleid.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, thanks for the help guys. I tried all the solutions, but none seemed to work so I submitted a ticket to google and they recommended one of the things I try is to use Xcode 9 instead of Xcode 9 beta, and that fixed everything. The tilt...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue please check following things: -

check console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials for your project and see whether there is already a client_id in OAuth 2.0 client IDs section , if so then copy that client id and replace it with you GoogleService-Info.plist file's CLIENT_ID and accordingly change REVERSED_CLIENT_ID (in reverse manner) now clean and build your app and test it will work

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you might have not add a URL scheme to your project

If you do not add a URL scheme into your, Follow some step to add

1. Open your project configuration: double-click the project name in
   he left tree view. Select your app from the **TARGETS** section,
   then select the **Info** tab, and expand the **URL Types** section.
2. Click the + button, and add a URL scheme for your reversed client ID. To find this value, open the `GoogleService-Info.plist` configuration file, and look for the **REVERSED_CLIENT_ID** key. Copy the value of that key, and paste it into the **URL Schemes** box on the configuration page. Leave the other fields blank.

[image]

**Note: Don't foget to check your client_id**

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I have done this already, or else my google sign-in wouldn't have worked before.

Comment: Have you checked your client_id?